# Catch Spotify app events in the background

Tags: spotify

I'm observing changes on the Player model and console.logging the currently played song.

When I switch away from the app it works fine - but only for a minute or so.

Is there a way to keep the app alive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, the app object only lives on for 60 seconds after the context has been deselected.